# Cannot Autowire DataSource in Spring Boot Project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jdbc, datasource

I am trying to build a simple Spring Boot CRUD application that also has login and signup options with spring boot security. I'm already working with a MySQL database and its working fine to persist the data for my application.

The problem is that, in trying to create my jdbcAuthentication, in my securityConfig class, it says that I cannot autowire Datasource, and that there are no beans of 'DataSource' type found (again, I have used my MySQL database successfully for this project, for a while now). It also automatically imports the javax.sql.DataSource import when I type it in, so it does recognize it.

I tried to search through similar questions, but just could not get it to work.

Here is my code:

**Test2Application.java**

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Test2Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Test2Application.class, args);
}
}
```

**SecurityConfig.java**

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

@EnableWebSecurity
@RequestMapping("cheese")
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
                .usersByUsernameQuery("select email as principal, password as credentials, true from user where email=?");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(
                        "/cheese/index",
                        "/cheese/",
                        "/**/webjars/**",
                        "/cheese/signup",
                        "/cheese/login",
                        "/cheese/account",
                        "/cheese/add",
                        "/cheese/remove",
                        "/cheese/success").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/cheese/login")
                .permitAll();

       http.csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

**UserController.java**

```
package com.example.demo.controllers;

import com.example.demo.models.Customer;
import com.example.demo.models.data.CustomerDao;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.Errors;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("cheese")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerDao customerDao;

    @RequestMapping(value = "login")
    public String loginPage(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("title", "Login Page");
        return "cheese/login";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "account")
    public String accountInfo(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("title", "Account Page");
        return "cheese/account";
    }

    @GetMapping("signup")
    public String displaySignUpForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("title", "Sign Up");
        model.addAttribute("customer", new Customer());
        return "cheese/signup";
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "signup")
    public String processSignUp(Model model, @ModelAttribute Customer customer, Errors errors) {

        if (errors.hasErrors()) {
            return "cheese/signup";
        }

        customerDao.save(customer);
        return "cheese/success";
    }
}
```

**Application.Properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:8889/******?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=****
spring.datasource.password=******

spring.jpa.database=MYSQL

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update

spring.jpa.show-sql=false

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

**Pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>test2</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>test2</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>webjars-locator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <addResources>true</addResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

The Spring Security configuration should applied with the `Configuration` annotation.
Remove `@RequestMapping("cheese")` from `SecurityConfig`

The correct configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. I made the changes and unfortunately got the same error (i.e. no beans of 'DataSource' type found).

Comment: Run the app with debug mode and check the auto configuration report. Can you share a location for the `application.properties` file?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, I created a separate config class where I defined a DataSource bean

```
@Bean
    DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setUrl("database_url");
        dataSource.setUsername("username");
        dataSource.setPassword("password");
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        return dataSource;
    }
```

and in the main config file (in your case Security config) left DataSource @Autowired.

```
@Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    protected void configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource);
    }
```

And it worked. In case it is useful, I used these Gradle dependencies -

```
implementation 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.18'
implementation group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-jdbc', version: '5.3.21'
```

Answer (score -2):

Apart from the `@Configuration` annotation, add `@EnableAutoConfiguration` which would attempt and configure code.

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableAutoConfiguration
    public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
```

Also, rebuild your sources afterwards.

Comment: `@SpringBootApplication` annotation can be used to enable those three features, that is:

`@EnableAutoConfiguration`: enable Spring Boot’s auto-configuration mechanism
`@ComponentScan`: enable `@Component` scan on the package where the application is located (see the best practices)
`@Configuration`: allow to register extra beans in the context or import additional configuration classes

Comment: @AntonNovopashin Hey, yeah I know that. But this is in the configuration class and not the main class. `@SpringBootApplication` is not necessary for this class since other annotations like `@ComponentScan` is not needed.